# xamarin form: is there any way to compress video file before we upload to server

Tags: forms, xamarin, video, compression

as when we use iphone 6 to record video, there is 130MB /min,
we have a program need user can record 5 min video, so nearly 600MB .

is there any way or sdk avaible in mobile client so we can use to compress video file before we upload to server?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?